# TO_DATE usage in Apache Drill to convert UNIXTIMESTAMP to human readable time format

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, apache-drill

My JSON file a timestamp field which is in UNIX upload timestamp format like `1501580484655`. This converts to GMT: `01-08-2017 9:41:24.655` AM

My attempt to convert this timestamp to human readable time format till millisecond is not working.

I have tried below till now:

1- `select TO_DATE(1501580484655) from (VALUES(1));`

O/P is  `2017-08-01` which is OK till date but I want till millisecond.

2- `select TO_DATE(1501580484655,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') from (VALUES(1));`

O/P is : `Error: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1501580484655" is malformed at "4655"`

3- `select TO_DATE(1501580484,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') from (VALUES(1));`

O/P is : `Error: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1501580484" is malformed at "4"`

4- `select TO_DATE(150158048,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') from (VALUES(1));`

O/P is : `Error: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "150158048" is too short`

5- `SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(1501580484655) from (VALUES(1));`

This works though. O/P is `49553-03-11 18:10:55.0`. And when I remove the last three characters 655 then I get O/P as `2017-08-01 09:41:24.0`

But When I run this query on my upload timestamp column from json file, then I get:

5a - `select TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR((cast(UploadTimeStamp as INTEGER)),1,10)) from dfs.root.`/test/`limit 5;`

O/P is:

```
`Error: SYSTEM ERROR: SchemaChangeException: Failure while trying to materialize incoming schema.  Errors:

Error in expression at index -1.  Error: Missing function implementation: [castTINYINT(VARCHAR-OPTIONAL)].  Full expression: --UNKNOWN EXPRESSION--..

Fragment 1:3

[Error Id: 7a91a9f8-9776-4f0d-9b9f-da3e65cc282a on rjio-devcluster1-BigdataNode1:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

Tried casting to various data types but same error is coming. Tried without cast and same error comes.

What should be the correct query to get O/P as `2017-08-01 HH:mm:ss.SSS`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To see millis in the output timestamp value you can specify floating number as a parameter for to_timestamp() function:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(1427936330) FROM (VALUES(1));
+------------------------+
|         EXPR$0         |
+------------------------+
| 2015-04-02 00:58:50.0  |
+------------------------+
1 row selected (1.612 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(1427936330.456) FROM (VALUES(1)); 
+--------------------------+
|          EXPR$0          |
+--------------------------+
| 2015-04-02 00:58:50.456  |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use `substr` on your data and then cast to INT.

For me it works:

**test.json:**
    {
        "timestamp": 1501580484655
    }

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select to_timestamp(cast(substr(`timestamp`, 
1, 10) as INTEGER)) from dfs.`tmp/test.json`;
+------------------------+
|         EXPR$0         |
+------------------------+
| 2017-08-01 02:41:24.0  |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: This works fine. But I tried getting the time in human readable format till milliseconds. I tried with select to_timestamp(cast(substr(gen.data.`Timestamp`, 1, 13) as INTEGER),'YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM:SS.sss') as TS from dfs.root.`/safe/dev1/` as gen limit 10; But it gave "Error: SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: 1501565396580" . And changing INTEGER to BIGINT gave Error: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1501543799231" is malformed at "9231"

Answer (score 1):

This works well after picking timestamp column from the record file.

```
 select to_timestamp(cast(CONCAT(substr(`Timestamp`, 1 , 10),'.',substr(`Timestamp`, CHAR_LENGTH(`Timestamp`)-3, 3)) as FLOAT)) from dfs.root.`/test/`;

+--------------------------+
|          EXPR$0          |
+--------------------------+
| 2017-08-04 10:00:01.792  |
+--------------------------+
```